# How to add empty UserControl of StackPanel programmatically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl, empty StackPanel like following.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="datawrapper" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Yellow"/>
</Grid>
```

Main window's XAML is like following.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="Gray">
        <StackPanel x:Name="holderpanel" Orientation="Vertical"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I want to put datawrapper into holderpanel from the Main Window's code behind programmatically.
If there's control in the datawrapper, dadawrapper is inserted into holder panel.
However, in case of empty StackPanel, never inserted.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To help you clarify your question, I'll provide an example of exactly what you asked for:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="Gray">
        <StackPanel x:Name="holderpanel" Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="datawrapper" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

codebehind (for this example, I added to Loaded event handler, but it could be used elsewhere):

```cs
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (datawrapper.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        var grid = datawrapper.Parent as Grid;
        grid.Children.Remove(datawrapper);

        holderpanel.Children.Add(datawrapper);
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to the limitation of comment, I left comment in the Answer.

Comment: @Don I think you need to try and break down what you're trying to do into _specific_ operations, and ask us which part you're having issues with. For example, when you say "If [X] happends, I need to do [Y].  How do I do this?", that's hard to answer without knowing which part of that you're having trouble with.  Are you not able to detect that [X] happened?  Or do you not know how to do [Y]?

Comment: I want to display data in the ScrollViewer. The StackPanel(holderpanel) is in the scrollviewer. each data item(ResultItem) is added into StackPanel(datawrapper). Each StackPanel(datawrapper) should have 5 items. New StackPanel(datawrapper) should be  added into the StackPanel(holderpanel). These should be done programmatically.

Comment: @Don  again, you list a set of requirements, sure.  But, which one of those are you having problems with?  For example, if you're asking how to programmatically add a stackpanel to another stackpanel, I showed an example of that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The datawrapper should be separated user control and empty like following.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="datawrapper" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Yellow"/>
</Grid>
```

I will add another user controls into the datawrapper horizontally 5 later. That user control is like following.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfTest.ResultItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid x:Name="resultitem">
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="#e0e0e0" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10 10 10 15">
        <Grid Margin="0 30 0 30" Background="White">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Chart#" Width="Auto" Height="30" Margin="5 5 0 5" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Patient Name" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="5 5 0 5" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Home Phone#" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="5 5 0 5" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Cell Phone#" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="5 5 0 5" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Patient Type" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="5 5 0 5" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

If the datawrapper is filled with 5 ResultItems, datawrapper will added into the holderpanel vertically.